# Depth First Search on graph java

Tags: java, graph, depth-first-search

I am having a bit of a problem implementing DFS traversal in java. My problem I think is the 'dfs' method in Graph.java I coded.  It is not returning the required output giving it a specific input. My code is below along with its input and desired output. Could someone help me solve this problem in my code. Thanks.

Graph.java

```
public class Graph {
ArrayList<Vertex> Vertices=new ArrayList<Vertex>();
Stack<Integer> stack=new Stack<Integer>();
public Graph(){
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    String sz=in.nextLine();
    int size=Integer.parseInt(sz);
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) addVertex();
    String s=in.nextLine();
    while(!s.equals("-1")){
        String[] arr=s.split(",");
        int v1=Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
        int v2=Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
        addEdge(v1,v2);
        s=in.nextLine();
    }

    //Vertex v=Vertices.get(2);
    //System.out.println(dfs(v));
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new Graph();
}
public void addVertex(){
    Vertex v=new Vertex(Vertices.size());
    Vertices.add(v);
}
public Vertex getVertex(int n){
    return Vertices.get(n);
}
public void addEdge(int n, int m){
    Vertex v1=Vertices.get(n);
    Vertex v2=Vertices.get(m);
    v1.addAdjacency(v2);
    v2.addAdjacency(v1);
}
public void dfs(Vertex obj){
    obj.marked=true;
    int k=0;
    for(Vertex v:obj.Vertices){
        Vertex d=v;
        if(!d.marked){
            d.parent=obj;
            k=d.parent.vertexNumber;
            stack.push(k);
            dfs(d);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Vertex.java

```
public class Vertex {
int vertexNumber;
Vertex parent = null;
boolean marked = false;
LinkedList<Vertex> Vertices = new LinkedList<Vertex>();

public Vertex(int num) {
    vertexNumber = num;
}

public void addAdjacency(Vertex object) {
    Vertices.add(object);
}

public boolean isAdjacent(Vertex object) {
    if (Vertices.contains(object))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public int getDegree() {
    return Vertices.size();
}
```

}
[image]

Comment: I have edited the DFS method

Comment: You `dfs` method returns `void`. How do you expect anything to be printed with `System.out.println(dfs(v));` ? It won't even compile.

Comment: Let me just correct that, it should be commented out

Comment: Also, you should tell us what do you want to do with `dfs`? It's hard to tell just by looking at your expected output. Do you want all reachable vertices from a source vertex?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what is needed all reachable vertices from a source vertex just as in the sample output

Comment: You really need to explain your sample output if you want us to help. You don't say this is the result from which source vertex (it looks like vertex 2 from your code?) and also don't say what does `1:0` really mean or what it is supposed to be. These should be part of your question.

Comment: output sample is not clear.

Comment: In addition to explaining the sample output, please also state the actual output, including any error messages. Your code looks basically correct. Did you intend to have a `stack.pop()` to balance your `stack.push()`?

Comment: In '1:0' for example, 1 is the vertex number and 0 is the parent vertex of 1. the source vertex is vertex 0. for each vertex, the vertex’s vertex number followed by ”:”, followed by the vertex number of its parent. It should not print this out for vertex 0 as it does not have a parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it. You don't need the stack in your dfs. Simplify it like this:

```
public void dfs(Vertex obj) {
    obj.marked = true;
    for (Vertex v : obj.Vertices) {
        if (!v.marked) {
            v.parent = obj;
            dfs(v);
        }
    }
}
```

Just print the results in your main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Graph g = new Graph();
    Vertex source = g.Vertices.get(0);
    g.dfs(source);

    for(Vertex v:g.Vertices){
        if (v!= source && v.marked){
            System.out.println(v.vertexNumber+":"+v.parent.vertexNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

You are simply calling dfs, marking anything reachable as you along and updating the parent. Once you are done, just go through all vertices and print the ones that were reachable (except the source itself).

And here is the output I'm getting:

```
1:0 
2:1 
3:8 
4:5 
5:6 
6:2 
7:10 
8:7 
9:5 
10:5
```

I also recommend you to refactor your code and move the command line reads to your main instead of `Graph` constructor. Just read the numbers and call `g.addEdge` in order to build your graph.